# Combine 3 tables to produce unique combination of all columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have 3 tables in R none of which share a common key.  I want to create a 4th table which combines all of the other tables where the rows are repeated so a unique combination of all 3 columns exists.

```
dt1 <- data.table(a = c(1,2,3,4,5))
dt2 <- data.table(b = c("a","b","c","d","e"))
dt3 <- data.table(c = c("p1", "p2", "p3"))
```

so for each row in dt3 you have a combination of dt1 and dt2

An example of the first few rows is below:

```
dt4 <- data.table(a = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3)), c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 3)), rep(c("p1", "p2", "p3"), 2))
```

So within the resulting table, each row is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `CJ`

```
CJ(a = dt1$a, b = dt2$b, c = dt3$c)
```

---

Or do this in a programmatic way

```
do.call(CJ, lapply(mget(paste0("dt", 1:3)), `[[`, 1))
```

Comment: thanks, it worked perfectly! 
Can I ask a stupid question - how did you know? Or how could I have found this out without asking on SO?

Comment: @MidnightDataGeek  Sorry, I was on a call.   It is from practise. If you start working on a language for several months/years, you will understand many functions and ways to manage it.

Comment: @Midnight Also, if you read `?data.table` and all the links under its "See Also" section, you'll have a good sense of what functionality is available.